# Quadratic Form Q(2x) = 4Q(x)??

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $Q(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}^TA\vec{x} $

Im trying to go from Q(2x) = 4Q(x).

What I have is $Q(2\vec{x})=(2\vec{x})^TA(2\vec{x})=4 \vec{x}^TA\vec{x}=4Q(\vec{x})$,

but I'm worried I'm using some undefined properties of multiplication. I just moved the 2's to the front, but again, am not sure if that's allowed.

Any input would be great, thanks.

Comment: Nope, those are totally defined properties of multiplication.  $A(2\vec x) = 2 A \vec x$, $(2\vec x)^T = 2 \vec x^T$, and $\vec x^T (2\vec y) = 2 \vec x^T \vec y$.

Comment: Yep, that's all good. No problems there.